# Найти сумму чисел

Tags: java

Пользователь вводит два числа и нужно найти сумму чисел между ними. Пример: 10 и 12, сумма которой будет 33. Но в моём случае программа почему-то всегда даёт сумму на три больше.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int m = scan.nextInt();
        int i = 0;
        if(m>n){
            while(n-1<m){
            n++;
            i +=n;
            }
            System.out.println(i);
      }
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: А формула арифметической прогрессии вам ни о чем не говорит?

Comment: @AzizUmarov о, неужели я встретил на практике проблему XY?

Comment: Вообще же, если опираться на ваш алгоритм, можно исправить так: `while(m >= n){i += n++;}`. По сути вы складываете числа `n + 1, n + 2 ... m + 1`, поэтому и выходит на 3(в случае 3 элементов) больше

Comment: @Miron В моей практике такого много. Человек пытается решить проблему каким-то изощренным путем и делает ошибки.

Comment: Про отладку кода вы никогда не слышали? Элементарная печать промежуточных значений помогла бы найти ошибку.

Comment: Очевидно, это не решение «проблемы», а обучение. Человеку дали задачу на циклы, а вы ему нерекуррентную формулу подсовываете))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

считайте по формуле [арифметической прогрессии](http://www.bymath.net/studyguide/alg/sec/alg29.html#:%7E:text=1%2C%201%2F2%2C%201,%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%20d%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B8.)

Сумма  n  первых членов арифметической прогрессии вычисляется как:

(a_1 + a_n)*n/2

в вашем случае это

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int m = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println((n + m)*(m - n + 1)/2);
        
    }
}
```

ну или по формуле

```
(n + m)*(m - n + 1)/2 это (10 + 12)*(12 - 10 + 1)/2 = 33
```